# What tune is Oliver Knox whistling in the 4400 episode 'Becoming'?

Tags: the-4400

The third episode of The 4400 ('Becoming') has a returnee who whistles what I'm sure is a TV or film theme tune while stalking some women and taking photos of them.

What is this tune? It drives me crazy every time I watch this episode, and it is not listed on the IMDB trivia page.

edit: i'll try and see if I can grab a clip of it tonight

Answer (score 1):

I think remember Oliver Knox whistling "Strangers in the night", while taking photos of a girl in the book store.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it wasn't that...